# Networking - Wired network works on Windows 8.1 but not on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, server, internet, ethernet

I have dual booted Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 15.04 on Asus xx130d laptop. I have wired internet connection. The problem I'm facing is I am not able to access internet on Ubuntu though I can access it on Windows.

I have read many posts about it but none of them helped me, I had tried Kubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 without installing it and in both OS net didn't connect. When I had  freshly installed Ubuntu, net was accessible but while installing updates from Ubuntu Software Centre it was taking too much time, so I just disconnected it and tried to reconnect it but it didn't connect.

`ifconfig`:

```
jalak@jalak-X555LJ:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 1c:b7:2c:02:ee:93  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1eb7:2cff:fe02:ee93/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:84412 errors:0 dropped:42955 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:322 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5096631 (5.0 MB)  TX bytes:24910 (24.9 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2993 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:241962 (241.9 KB)  TX bytes:241962 (241.9 KB)

`
```

`ping -3c www.google.com`:

```
jalak@jalak-X555LJ:~$ ping -c3 www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

`modinfo e1000e | grep version`:

```
version:        2.3.2-k
srcversion:     929F414C06EA93D9C5F9663
vermagic:       3.19.0-25-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

`ipconfig /all` from Windows:

```
PPP adapter gtpl:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : gtpl
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 103.251.213.247(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-B7-2C-02-EE-93
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4c09:d085:de12:d31b%3(Preferred) 
Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.211.27(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1(Duplicate) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::fd9f:9d37:ac34:63cb%3
                                    192.168.1.2
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 253540140
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-A2-5A-E4-1C-B7-2C-02-EE-93
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                    8.8.4.4
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

`lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2`:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Please do not post all kinds of Windows outputs, it can not help.

Comment: ok... added output of lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2..